# Crystal Reports Next day report ran daily

Tags: function, date, crystal-reports

I have a report ran daily for tomorrow's schedule - I am using the dateadd function;

```
dateadd ("d",1,currentdate)
```

and it works great. However, when Friday comes I need to run it for Monday, but I am not sure how to write this as Crystal will not accept any of my attempts.

Using If, Then, with a count of 2,3,4,5 for M,T,W,TH

I am not sure if I am even on the right track.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Crystal will not accept any of my attempts?"  Exactly *what* are you trying to do, and *what happens* when you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to determine if the day of the week you are running the report is a Friday or not.  You can use the Weekday function to perform this:[IBM's website has an example here.](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsawshlp/v7r5m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic679.html)

Once you have determined what the weekday is, you can conditionally use your DateAdd function.  IE: If day is Friday, then add three days to get to the next Monday.

```
if Weekday(currentdate,crMonday)=5 then
DateAdd("d",3,currentdate)
else
DateAdd("d",1,currentdate)
```